# use same php session on another website on link click

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a question. Let's say I am on website **domain1.com** and I click on a link on **domain1.com** that brings me to **domain2.com**. But I want to use the same `session_id()` that was set with `session_start()` in **domain1.com** on **domain2.com**. How do I accomplish this in PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: you own both domains? are they hosted on the same server?

Comment: I see what you want to do here. Just domain (HTTP_HOST) will be different but the server is same. Or there are really 2 separate sites?

Comment: They are two separate sites. I have access to certain information in domain2.com from domain1.com, but they are two completely different websites. They are not hosted on the same server and yes I own both domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `session_id()` itself doen't contain any data, there are a couple of things to consider:

- If the session is set in a cookie, you can't transfer it (unless to a subdomain), make sure you transfer it via GET
- In order to have the data associated with the SESSION sync accross the servers, you have to share the file system (e.g. via [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.org/)), at least for the path the SESSIONS are saved (e.g. /tmp/php)
- if you save objects in the SESSION make sure they are available on both servers

If both domains are pointing to the same document root on the same server you only need to take care about the first point

If you only want to use the `session_id()` and not the associated data, you can just set the id: `session_id('yourSessionIdFromDomain1')`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a MySql Database which you can access from both Sites...

Like:

```
Table _sessions -> Fields('access_token','session_vars')
```

in session_vars you can save `$_SESSION` each time a site loads.
access_token should be a unique string who is generated when the user comes to the Website first.

This is very dangerous!! 11  :-)