# Check if cookie exists on website

Tags: php, session, drupal, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to redirect my users of my website toa  page if a certain session cookie exists. The session cookie is from another website and called pubcookie_l. How do I see if this cookie exists when on my website, perhaps checking in php? Thanks.

Comment: sorry you can't do it, are you in control of both websites? or is one with the pubcookie_l a 3rd party?

Comment: I don't think it's possible... Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540725/use-same-php-session-on-another-website-on-link-click

Comment: No, the 3rd party website is from my university. My website uses the university ldap to log in. I'm trying to do this: When the user logs in to the university website and comes to my site, they should automatically be taken to my log in page.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You can not check some other domains cookie on different domain.

However you can check the **Referer**. If the referer is your university's website.

In PHP Referer can be accessed by `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies don't exist "on the website", they exist on the client. And the client doesn't (shouldn't) give any cookies to a domain that didn't set it.

If it did, that would be a huge security risk (cookies often contain passwords or other sensitive information, even though they shouldn't), not to mention privacy concerns.